# How to train my QnA Bot while using it?

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I made a QnA bot using bot-framework SDK3 and QnAmaker service.
As I know, we can train our  [knowledge base](https://www.qnamaker.ai/). But I don't know how to train it while using my QnA bot in other channels like teams.

I think I can let user judge whether the bot's answer has solved the problem. So I make the conversation like below.

User: Ask a question

bot: give a answer

**bot: does it solve your problem? yes or no?**

**user: yes/no**

At this time, how could I let my knowledge base know it and master it? Then next time my bot may give a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog-based training like you described above is not currently supported in the current (GA) release of the QnA Maker. It is, however, something that the dev team is looking into. Currently, you can only train the QnAMaker portion of your bot from the QnA Maker portal.

Comment: Do you know active learning which i read here https://www.qnamaker.ai/old/Documentation/ActiveLearning  ? Do you think it would help me solve my problem?

Comment: This feature was from the preview version of QnA Maker and was removed from the GA version. They're currently working on it as a possibility for the GA version, but as it currently stands, it's Active Learning doesn't function.

Comment: So is the API[Train Knowledge Base] not available in GA version?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can handle this kind of problem by Scores property

100     An exact match of user query and a KB question

90  High confidence - most of the words match

40-60   Fair confidence - important words match

10  Low confidence - important words don't match

0   No word match

reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/confidence-score

Comment: I know the score systems. I have to say it depends on the user's how to ask questions. if it is not a good question which users always asked, i want to teach my bot to answer it correctly. That's why I want to train it while user using it

Comment: User query can be different . When user ask any question save this question somewhere else if this question is appropriate  then add this question as  alternative question . Now in your chatbot's database  2 questions  are mapped to one answer. Now you're chatbot is more trained as compared to previous one..