# How to use metadata and train Knowledge Base automatically C# QnA maker Bot

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

My FAQ bot is using this [QnAMakerDialog](https://github.com/garypretty/botframework/tree/master/QnAMakerDialog) which is **not using** Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker, but easy to use metadatas.

However I also want to train[**CustomFeedBack, ActiveLearning**] like these [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/QnAMaker) which is **using** Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker.

Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker provides method like **QnAFeedbackStepAsync**.

**Q1:** Does [QnAMakerDialog](https://github.com/garypretty/botframework/tree/master/QnAMakerDialog) which is **not using** Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker have some similar methods like QnAFeedbackStepAsync ?

**Q2:** How to use metadata while **using** Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker ?

**Q3:** QnA Maker REST API V4.0 don't support to use train knowledgebases.
Although my bot is using V3.0, is it better not to use train knowledgebases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to train my QnA Bot while using it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924667/how-to-train-my-qna-bot-while-using-it)

Comment: Sorry for my bad descriptions. I tried to make it clearly.

Comment: Are CustomFeedBack and 
 ActiveLearning in Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker preview version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user ask any question save this question somewhere else if this question is appropriate then add this question as alternative question . Now in your chatbot's database 2 questions are mapped to one answer. Now you're chatbot is more trained as compared to previous one.. by this you can manage log of chatbot