# How to add active learning to Azure Chat Bot with C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I have made a chat bot with LUIS and QnA, but now I want to add active learning to the QnA, but the problem is I'm only able to found documentation for node.js, **whereas my project is in c# and .net framework.** Kindly provide some useful links where I can found the documentation and steps for implementing active learning to QnA.

This [here](https://www.qnamaker.ai/old/Documentation/ActiveLearning) is available but not for c# .net

Comment: Could you describe more in detail what you mean by "active learning"?

Comment: hi @rudolf just go to this link, I believe you will understand. https://www.qnamaker.ai/old/Documentation/ActiveLearning

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to train my QnA Bot while using it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924667/how-to-train-my-qna-bot-while-using-it)

Answer (score 0):

Dialog-based training like you described above is not currently supported in the current (GA) release of the QnA Maker. It is, however, something that the dev team is looking into. Currently, you can only train the QnAMaker portion of your bot from the QnA Maker portal.